# Send file length with outputstream and receive length and byte[] with inputstream for streaming frames from one device to the other Android/Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I have searched and searched and everything I have found has been helpful but I keep getting an out of memory error. The images I send are .06 MB so I know the problem isn't from decoding the byte[] into a bitmap. When I remove the while loops this works like a charm for one frame but I want multiple frames. I am getting a byte[] and sending it to a different device using sockets but I am at a loss how to do this. My problem is that I don't send and receive the correct byte[] length. This is what i am doing currently.

```
while (count != -1) {

     //first send the byte[] length
     dataOutputStream.writeInt(sendPackage.length);

     //pass a byte array
     publishProgress("sending file to client");
     showMyToastOnUiThread(String.valueOf(sendPackage.length));
     outputStream.write(sendPackage, 0, sendPackage.length);
     outputStream.flush();
}
```

Receive byte[] on different device:

```
int count = inputStream.read();
while (count != -1) {
     int byteArrayLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
     Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Starting convert to byte array");

     byte[] receivedBytes = convertInputStreamToByteArray(inputStream, byteArrayLength);

     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.length);
     publishProgress(bitmap);
}

//convert inputstream to byte[]
    public byte[] convertInputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inputStream, int readLength) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[readLength];
        try {

            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Starting convert to byte array while loop");
            int readTotal = 0;
            int count = 0;

            while (count >= 0 && readTotal < readLength) {
                count = inputStream.read(data, readTotal, readLength - readTotal);
                if (readLength > 0) {
                    readTotal += count;
                }
            }

            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Finished convert to byte array while loop");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: What does `publishProgress(bitmap)` do? And you know that first `count` never changes after first setting?

Comment: The receiving end starts by reading a single byte: `int count = inputStream.read();` and then loops while count != -1. But this byte isn't sent by the sender, and `count` is never changed inside the loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I am doing all my work inside an AsyncTask (a thread) and the way to publish something to the ui thread and still keep the AsyncTask running is by publishProgress(). It calls a method that pushes to the ui thread.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to read in byte[]s that have a specific length until the socket disconnects. how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
int count = inputStream.read();
while (count != -1) {
```

You're consuming a byte and then ignoring it. That means the next value you read (the size) will be incorrect. You need a different way of telling whether you're at the end of the stream. Some options:

- Send a -1 when you're finished; that way you can stop as soon as `readInt` returns -1
- If you know it, send the number of images you're going to send before you start sending them
- Use `mark(1)`, then `read()`, then `reset()` - if your stream supports marking. I don't know whether it will or not. You could always wrap it in `BufferedInputStream` if not.
- Reimplement `DataInputStream.readInt` yourself in a way which detects the end of the stream as being an expected possibility instead of throwing an exception
- Just catch an exception in `readInt` (not nice - getting to the end of the stream isn't really exceptional)

Comment: I want the images to send as long as the socket is open. When the socket sending the images closes readInt will be -1 right? I see the count isn't getting reset but that shouldn't matter when trying to detect the end of a file should it?

Comment: @user3052223: No, when the socket closes `readInt` will throw an `IOException`.

Comment: Ok I removed the inputstream.read() and it works. Now i am just running out of memory in about a second because of the bitmapfactory.decodebytearray(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3052223: I would add diagnostics to check that you're allocating the right sizes - but if you are, it may just be that you haven't got enough memory for all those images.

Comment: It is because I am running out of memory. Its a bummer I can deallocate memory in java... garbage collection isn't quick enough.

Comment: @user3052223: In almost all cases, garbage collection really *is* quick enough - the VM will do a full GC before blowing up in your face. I've very rarely seen it fail when there really *is* enough memory available.

Comment: I'm sending five images a second that i have compressed down to 5% quality of the original image and it runs for 5 - 10 seconds then gives me an outofmemory error. I think its because the nexus 7 tablet i am running it on only has 1 gig of ram and in Android each application can only use a portion of that memory. I recycle() the bitmap after i am done with it. The only other thing i can think of some sort of c++ library that can deallocate memory on bitmap objects not being used anymore. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user3052223: I'm afraid not - but one thing to watch out for is that the RAM used *may* only depend on the size of the image in pixels, not the quality - in other words, it may be that the images are simply too large to handle. But I don't have enough Android experience to say any more with any degree of certainty.